# Proving $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are entire functions such that $(f\circ g)(z)$ is a non constant polynomial. Show that both $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are polynomials.

I tried by contradiction: Ruling out $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ one by one by assuming not a polynomial. And the hint given in the book is to use the Casorati-Weierstrass Theorem.
"The analytic function with isolated singularity at $a$ maps a punctured neighbourhood of $a$ to a dense set in $\mathbb{C}$

I am not sure I am on the right way or not?

I need help. Please some one suggest me.

Comment: You are on the right way. If $f\circ g$ is a non-constant polynomial, then $(f\circ g)(z_n) \to \infty$ for all sequences $z_n\to \infty$. And if $h$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$, then there is a sequence $w_n\to \infty$ with $h(w_n) \to 0$ by Casorati-Weierstraß. Set $h = g$ to show $g$ must be a polynomial, then $h = f$ to show that $f$ also must be one.

Comment: Thank you , I got this idea.

Comment: entire = holomorphic ?

Comment: @idm "entire = holomorphic on all of $\mathbb{C}^n$ (here, $n = 1$)" (Note that one also speaks of entire meromorphic functions or entire harmonic functions, but without further qualification, it means "entire holomorphic" in every instance I have come across so far.)

Answer (score 3):

We can use the following fact:

> An entire function is polynomial if and only if $\infty$ is not an essential singularity.

By assumption, $\infty$ is *not* an essential singularity of $f\circ g$. Hence by Casaroti-Weierstrass, for a suitable neighbourhood $U=\{\,z\in \mathbb C:|z|>r\,\}$ of $\infty$, the image $f(g(U))$ is not dense in $\mathbb C$, say it avoids a disk $B(z_0,\rho)$.
If $g(U)$ is dense, this implies that $f(\mathbb C)$ avoids $B(z_0,\rho)$ as well, $\frac1{f(z)-z_0}$ is bounded, hence constant, hence $f$ finally and $f\circ g$ are constant, contradiction.
We conclude that $g(U)$ is not dense, i.e. $\infty$ is not an essential singularity of $g$, so $g$ is a nonconstant polynomial.
Consequently, $g(U)$ is a neighbourhood of $\infty$ and its image under $f$ is not  dense, i.e. $f$ has no essential singularity at $\infty$ so that $f$ is polynomial.