# Entire function whose square or composition with itself is a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function whose square $f^2$ is a polynomial. Then is $f$ a polynomial as well?

I think due to the Great Picard Theorem, since $f$ cannot assume any complex value infinitely many times, it is forced to be a polynomial. Is my argument correct?

Also if $f$ is an entire function such that $f(f(z))$ is a polynomial, the same reasoning with the Great Picard Theorem shows that $f$ is again forced to be a polynomial.

Would anyone please give me a comment on my argument?

Comment: Both arguments sound good.  Make sure that you can solidly argue the essential point (if $f$ assumes a value infinitely often then so do $f^2$ and $f\circ f$).

Comment: Casorati-Weierstraß is sufficient, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991928/proving-fz-and-gz-are-polynomials.

Comment: @MartinR I see. I personally like the Picard Theorem so I used it. Thank you for other solutions.

Comment: @ErickWong Of course I did so. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 4):

Picard's Theorem is an overkill for this.

If $g$ is entire and non-constant then $g$ is a polynomial iff $|g(z)| \to \infty$ as $|z| \to \infty$.

[ This is proved by first getting rid of the finite number of zeros of $g$ (by dividing by  a polynomial and the considering $\frac 1 g$].

The case of $f^{2}$ follows trivially from this.

For $f(f(z))$ suppose $|z_n| \to \infty$. Then  $|f(f(z_n))| \to \infty$ unless it is constant (in which case it is easy to show that $f$ is itself  a constant). If $f(z_n)$ has  a bounded subsequence then $f(f(z_n))$ would be bounded along the subsequence, a contradiction. Thus $|f(z)| \to \infty$ as $|z| \to \infty$.