# A non-entire function whose square and composition of itself are polynomials.

Tags: polynomials, examples-counterexamples, functional-equations

This post is closely related to [Entire function whose square or composition with itself is a polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3337332/entire-function-whose-square-or-composition-with-itself-is-a-polynomial).

In the linked post, the OP asked to prove the following:

> 1. If $f:\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is entire, and $f^{2}(z)$ is a polynomial, then $f$ is also a polynomial.
> 2. If $f:\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is entire, and $f(f(z))$ is a polynomial, then $f$ is also a polynomial.

Several proofs were given: see [Proving $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991928/proving-fz-and-gz-are-polynomials) for a proof using Casorati-Weierstrass Theorem, and [Two confusions on Great Picard Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3933426/two-confusions-on-great-picard-theorem) for a proof using Great Picard Theorem.

---

My question is what if $f$ is not entire in the first place, does $f^{2}(z)$ being a polynomial still imply $f$ being a polynomial? and does $f(f(z))$ being a polynomial imply $f$ be a polynomial?

As the proof depends heavily on the entire property of $f$, I believe the answer for both of my questions is NO.

But I cannot find a counterexample.

For the first one, I tried $f(z):=|z|$, but then $f(z)\neq z^{2}$, because $|z|$ is a complex norm, so that $$f(z)=|z|^{2}=x^{2}+y^{2}\neq z^{2}=x^{2}+2ixy-y^{2}.$$

Without absolute value, I am not sure what else I can try since $f^{2}(z)$ must be a polynomial (so all the fraction without removable singularities seems not work well..)

For the second one, perhaps we can use $f(z):=\dfrac{1}{z}$ which has a pole at $z=0$, and $f(f(z))=z$ is a polynomial.

Is my second example correct? Any idea about the first example? Thank you!

Comment: So, you are assuming *nothing* about $f$ other than that $f^2$ or $f\circ f$ is a polynomial functions? Is that it?

Comment: $\sqrt z$ is analytic on $\mathbb C -\mathbb R_{-}$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos yes.

Comment: If $f$ is not required to be continuous, then let $f(x)=x$ for every value except $x=1$ and let $f(1)=-1$.

Comment: @lulu oh.... right... then $f^{2}(x)=x^{2}$ for all $x$

Comment: @lulu nice example.

Comment: Or$$f(z)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }z\in\Bbb Q\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Then $f\circ f$ is the constant polynomial function $1$.

Comment: if you require $f$ continuous on $\mathbb C$ and $f^2$ polynomial, it actually follows that $f$ is a polynomial

Comment: @Conrad why is that?

Comment: because $f$ is analytic except at the zeroes (compose $g=f^2$ with the appropriate branch of the analytic square root near any point where $f(w) \ne 0$) and they are isolated unless $f$ is identically zero, so by continuity they are removable, hence $f$ is entire

Comment: @Conrad I am sorry for the silly question, but I don't follow why $f$ is analytic except at the zeros. So we say a function $f(z)$ is analytic at $z_{0}$ if $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}(z-z_{0})^{n}$ converges in $D_{z_{0}}(r)$ for some $r$. I don't even follow why we can express a continuous function in power series...

Comment: also note that $f(z)=\bar z$ is not analytic but highly smooth (harmonic etc) and $f\circ f$ is a polynomial the second problem is trickier even in the continuous or even $C^{\infty}$ say case

Comment: $f^2=P$ implies $f=\sqrt P$ (locally for an appropriate branch of the square root as long as we stay away from zeroes) and as noted the square root is analytic outside zeroes of $P$

Comment: @Conrad oh okay. I get it. You combined the continuity of $f$ and $f^{2}$ being a polynomial. Nice!

Comment: if $f^2=g, g$ is analytic and $f$ continuous, then $f$ analytic; in other words a continuous square root of an analytic function is analytic - the crucial word being continuous of course

Comment: @Conrad Thank you so much for these nice comments :)!

Comment: @Conrad oh sorry for coming back. I was confused for a while by the complex square root, and searched it for a while. Okay, so the example you gave, $\sqrt{z}$, you mean the principal branch of the square root right? which is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$. And for the later discussion, $\sqrt{P}$ is analytic outside the zeros of the polynomial $P$. does this also hold for, say, some general analytic function $g$?

Comment: yes it does hold - see my comment above; continuous roots of analytic functions are analytic (could be cube root too, etc); the point is that locally roots are "separated" outside zeroes, so continuity forces to choose the same branch locally, hence implies analyticity outside zeroes and then the zeroes are isolated etc; if you study the modern proof of the Riemann Mapping Theorem, you will see the square root trick which uses precisely this separation, to create functions with disjoint images

Comment: @Conrad nice. Thank you for the patient clarification. Recently I found so many subtitles in complex analysis I didnt realize before..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean with 'not entire' ?

$f(z)=1/z^n$ gives $f(f(z))=z^{n^2}$

with $\phi$ biholomorphic (or just bijective ?) on the right open set then
$g(z)= \phi^{-1}(1/\phi(z))$ gives $g(g(z)) = z$,

same for $h(z)= \phi^{-1}(1-\phi(z)),h(h(z))=z$.